# How can i run "exec" function in php for running a python file in a server, can i use a url or only a filesystem path?

Tags: php, python, apache

I wrote a short python script and i use "exec" in php for running that script. The python and php files are uploaded in a university server with apache webserver that is installed on windows. I installed on windows (at the university server) the python exe file python2.7.

Php does not receive data with exec:

```
 array(0) { } Array ( ) after output
```

I tried system() function:

```
before exec vardump int(2) mystring string(0) "" printr output 2
```

PHP code:

```
     echo "before exec";
         $command = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\path\\py\\prova.py"; 
     $command .= " $param1 2>&1";
    $mystring = system($command, $output);
    print(" vardump ");
    var_dump($output);
    print(" mystring ");
    var_dump($mystring);
    print(" printr output ");
    print_r($output);
```

python code:

```
#PATHMAIN
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    sys.argv[1].replace("\\\\", "\\")
    path1img = sys.argv[1]
else:
    path1img = "http://site/folder/Images/Highres/d (0).jpg" 


def comparison(path1img):

    import numpy as np
    from numpy import array
    import cv2
    import predict as pr
    #import bp1img
    import moduloSkeleton

    listafeaturevector = list()
    featurev = list()
    sep = list()
    sbp = list()
    sangle = list()
    a = 111111111111111111111111111111
    print("hello")
    return a
```

I tried also

```
$command = "python \site\py\prova.py";

$command = "python http://site\\folder\\py\\prova.py";

$command = "C:Python27\\python http://site\\folder\\py\\prova.py";

$command = "C:Python27\\ \\folder\\py\\prova.py"

$command = "python27 \\folder\\py\\prova.py"

$command = "python27 http://site\\folder\\py\\prova.py"

$command = "C:\\python27\\python C:\\path\\py\\prova.py"
```

Comment: Don't mind me - I just read your PHP code as Python. As far as the Python goes, have you tries accessing the URL through a browser to verify its operation?

Comment: Also, while I do not know PHP, 40+ years of experience is telling me that it was designed to run a program that lives on the local disk of the server, and not suck random code in from the Internet in the hope that nobody was feeling malicious today. But then, 40+ years as a programmer can turn you into a crabby old cynic :-)

Comment: Yes! Both php file and python file are in the same server! I do not know other alternative for interfacing the 2 languages.

Comment: "http://site\\folder\\py\\prova.py" - backslashes? Are you sure? Try to open the url from browser - it must output correct source code, not interpretedresult. Or you should use filesystem paths, not urls.

Comment: I tried also: $command = "python http: //site/folder/py/prova.py"; and does not work. So it works only if i use filesystem path of the server for running the file?

Comment: OK, here's a really dumb question. You have a file called prova.py on your server. When someone makes some kind of HTTP request to your server, you want your server to respond by running a Python program (that lives on the server's disk) and sending the results back to the browser (or other web client)?

A cursory reading of http://us1.php.net/function.exec suggests that what you actually need is closer to

Comment: first question: yes! I will try to put the real path of python file hoping that it works like when i programmed in my local webserver!

Comment: the error is in the quote! $command = 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe "C:\\path\\py\\comparisonNosvm.py"';

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a really dumb question. You have a file called `prova.py` on your server. When someone makes some kind of HTTP request to your server, you want your server to respond by running a Python program (that lives on the server's disk) and sending the results back to the browser (or other web client)?

A cursory reading of https://www.php.net/function.exec suggests that what you actually need is closer to `exec("/disk/path/to/prova.py")`. If that doesn't work, I got nothing. And as to what you do with the output, well, sorry, I'm a Python programmer. Don't see the PHP crew clamoring to help ...

Comment: First question yes, i tried to put a path and not a.url like when.i programming in my locali webserver

Comment: I put the right server path: $command = "C:\\python27\\python C:\\path\\py\\prova.py"; but no data!

Comment: In which case you need someone who understands PHP. Sorry!

Comment: System($command, $output) function print me: (2) 2.  What does it mean?

Comment: @postgresm I might be late in posting this, but if it is any consolation, visit this link of mine, where I had the trouble executing python script. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304142/trying-to-execute-python-command-through-php-but-permission-errors) is the link to it.